# PHP form validation and scroll up to top of form if there are errors

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a contact form, and I'm using php to check for input errors (empty fields, invalid names, and an invalid email address). It works fine, but after it detects the errors it goes back to the top of the page, so the user has to scroll back down to see the form and error signs. I am trying to use `header("Location:fullURL")` to redirect to `#title` (`id="title"` is the top of the form) if errors are detected, but once it redirects, the variables that the user inputed (and the error messages that were set up when checking the form) are lost, so it displays an empty form.  Is there a way to redirect the user to `#title` without losing those variables?

Thank you

PHP Code:

```
<?php
$myemail = "myactualemailaddress@domain.com";
$title = "#title";
$thankyou = "thankyou.html";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["firstName"])) {
        $fNameErr = "Please enter your first name";
        $submitErr = "Please review any fields with errors above and try again";
    } else {
        $firstName = test_input($_POST["firstName"]);
        // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$firstName)) {
            $fNameErr = "Please use only letters and white spaces";
            $submitErr = "Please review any fields with errors above and try again";
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["lastName"])) {
        $lNameErr = "Please enter your last name";
        $submitErr = "Please review any fields with errors above and try again";
    } else {
        $lastName = test_input($_POST["lastName"]);
        // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$lastName)) {
            $lNameErr = "Please use only letters and white spaces";
            $submitErr = "Please review any fields with errors above and try again";
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $emailErr = "Please enter your email address";
        $submitErr = "Please review any fields with errors above and try again";
    } else {
        $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
        // check if e-mail address is well-formed
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $emailErr = "Please enter a valid email address"; 
            $submitErr = "Please review any fields with errors above and try again";
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["subject"])) {
        $subjectErr = "Please enter your subject";
        $submitErr = "Please review any fields with errors above and try again";
    } else {
        $subject = test_input($_POST["subject"]);
        $subjectedit = "Contact Form: " . $subject;
    }

    if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
        $messageErr = "Please enter your message";
        $submitErr = "Please review any fields with errors above and try again";
    } else {
            $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
    }

    $subscribe = test_input($_POST["subscribe"]);

    if(empty($submitErr)) {
        mail($myemail, $subjectedit, $message, "From: $firstName $lastName <$email>");
        header('HTTP/1.0 302 Found');
        header('Location: http://omarhaddad.com/MAIN/Contact/thankyou.html');
    }

}

function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}

if(!empty($submitErr)) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 302 Found');
    if (headers_sent()) {
    die("Error: headers already sent!");
    } else {
    header("Location: http://omarhaddad.com/MAIN/Contact/#title", true);
    }
}
?>
```

HTML Code:

```
<h2 id="title">Send me a message!</h2>

<form id="form" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">

    <label for="firstName">First Name</label><br />

    <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" value="<?php echo $firstName;?>" style="width: 100%;">

    <br /><span class="error" id="wfirst"><?php echo $fNameErr;?><br /></span><br />

    <label for="lastName">Last Name</label><br />

    <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" size="50" value="<?php echo $lastName;?>">

    <br /><span class="error" id="wlast"><?php echo $lNameErr;?><br /></span><br />

    <label for="email">Email Address</label><br />

    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" size="50" value="<?php echo $email;?>">

    <br /><span class="error" id="wemail"><?php echo $emailErr;?><br /></span><br />

    <label for="subject">Subject</label><br />

    <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" size="50" value="<?php echo $subject;?>">

    <br /><span class="error" id="wsubject"><?php echo $subjectErr;?><br /></span><br />

    <label for="message">Message</label><br />

    <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="10" cols="50"><?php echo $message;?></textarea>

    <br /><span class="error" id="wmessage"><?php echo $messageErr;?><br /></span><br />

    <label for="subscribe">Would you like me to add your email address to my newsletter?</label><br />

    <input type="checkbox" id="subscribe" name="subscribe" checked="checked"><label for="subscribe">Yes</label><br />

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

    <br /><span class="error" id="wsubmit"><?php echo $submitErr;?><br /></span><br />

</form>
```

Comment: The response to the POST needs to use the bookmark on the URL.  You are doing essentially a second redirect, losing your state.  You could use a little JavaScript... I'd look into `scrollIntoView`... probably easiest way.

Comment: doh, or just place the anchor/bookmark on the URI used in the action of the form?  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25531543/jump-to-html-anchor-automatically-when-php-form-submits

Comment: You could return the user to your named anchor AND show them their previous inputs, but you'd have to store those inputs in your session, and then populate the values based on what's in the session. For instance: `value = "<?php if(isset($_SESSION['postvars']['field'])) echo $_SESSION['postvars']['field`]; ?>"` don't forget to unset those variables at your page footer, otherwise they'll be stuck in your session the whole time

Comment: Thank you ficuscr!!  It's working perfect now.